# clang and gcc different behavior with compound literal

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c99, compound-literals

Came across compound literal recently, and as far as I understand it, the following is the correct way of using it. Fortunately, it works both with gcc and clang on ubuntu.

```
int main() {
  int *p = (int []) {1, 2};
  return 0;
}
```

However, I notice another way of using compound literal, shown below. It feels a bit weird; this is just array initializer. The following code compiles fine with clang, but failed with gcc, `array initialized from non-constant array expression`.

```
int main() {
  int p[] = (int []) {1, 2};
  return 0;
}
```

Is this intentional or what?

ENV:

- gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
- Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)

CMD:

- gcc test.c
- clang test.c

Comment: What is the command line used to compile them?

Comment: @jww Edited to add the cmd used for building.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer: Clang confesses that the program uses an extension

Accepting what you wrote, `int p[] = (int []) {1, 2};`, is a Clang extension. GCC is allowed to reject it, because it is not part of C99 (the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) introduced compound literals and can be used as reference).

In fact, my version of Clang can be made to emit a warning on your program. It is funny that it calls your line a “GNU extension”:

```
~ $ clang -std=c99 -pedantic t.c
t.c:2:7: warning: initialization of an array of type 'int []' from a compound
      literal of type 'int [2]' is a GNU extension
      [-Wgnu-compound-literal-initializer]
  int p[] = (int []) {1, 2};
      ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
~ $ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

### Long answer

The line `int p[] = (int []) {1, 2};` is a declaration. It should follow the syntax given in clause 6.7:

> **6.7 Declarations**
>
> Syntax
>
> 1
>
> ```
> declaration:
>     declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
>
> declaration-specifiers:
>     storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
>     function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
>
> init-declarator-list:
>     init-declarator
>     init-declarator-list , init-declarator
>
> init-declarator:
>     declarator
>     declarator = initializer
> ```

All lies on the definition of *initializer*, which can be found in 6.7.8:

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> 1
>
> ```
> initializer:
>     assignment-expression
>     { initializer-list }
>     { initializer-list , }
> …
> ```
>
> …
>
> 12 The rest of this subclause deals with initializers for objects that have aggregate or union type.
>
> …
>
> 16 Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type **shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members**.

The emphasis in 6.7.8:16 is mine. Basically, this is the part of the C99 standard that your program does not satisfy.

Comment: GCC seems to implement this only for objects with static storage duration (`static int p[] = (int []) {1, 2};`). But Clang also implements it for ones with automatic storage duration. Weird. Could've been an oversight when it was implemented in Clang as the test cases in test/Sema/array-init.c don't include such a case.

Answer (score -1):

Compound literal has different behavior in C99 and C++.

In C++ it has only a single expression storage duration, not automatic duration. If this is compiled in C++ mode, then it won't work, because the compound literal object disappears after the expression finishes.

This might explain @cremno's description on static vs automatic storage duration.

Comment: Compound literals are not a part of standard C++ at all.